# How to perform a log transformation on data that has zero values

Tags: r, nan, transformation, skew

I am trying to log transform my data with the following...

```
skew(data_1)

any(data_1 == 0) 
data_1_no_zero <- data_1 != 0

transform <- log(data_1_no_zero) 
skew(transform)

[1] NaN
```

But I get a following output of NaN which I know is not a number. Can anyone help figure out what is wrong with this or what else could be done to get a better output?

Comment: log1p(x): computes log(1+x). This will take care of 0s in your data and still does a log transform

Comment: You might also try a different transformation, like `sqrt`, that can handle zeros.

Comment: @AcademicDialysis thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

Your proximal problem is that you should write

```
data_1_no_zero <- data_1[data_1 != 0]
```

That is, *select the elements* of `data_1` that are non-zero.  `na.omit(log(data_1))` would also work, although removing zeros first is arguably better (farther upstream).

As to what you should do more broadly - use a different transformation, remove zeros, add 1/use `log1p()`, add a small constant (e.g. `data_1 <- data_1 + min(data_1[data_1>0])/2`) ... that very much depends on your context/what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks so much @BenBolker! I will give this a try!

Comment: Be aware that changing the value added before log-transforming can drastically change the distribution of the transformed data.